# Calculating the Size of a Power Set with Specific Conditions

Tags: combinatorics

I have two sets, N and D, each of which is the power set of all elements between 0 and K (inclusive). I am interested in computing the size of a new set ND.

The set ND is defined as follows: it consists of all sets such that the cardinality (or size) of each set n in N is less than R times the cardinality of each set d in D (R is a positive number greater than 1). In mathematical terms, this condition can be written as $ND=\{|n| < R * |d| :  \forall n \in N, d \in D\}$

I don't have mathematical intuition on how to work this out, so I programmatically calculated the  $|N|/(|n||d|)$ for R=1.1, and K between 3 and 19, (see python code at end) and I end up with a function that doesn't appear to be strictly increasing.

[image]

I'm curious to hear thoughts on how to mathematically derive the growth of ND, particularly with growing K. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

````
from itertools import chain, combinations
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import jit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    # power set sizes
    return list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1)))

@jit(nopython=True)
def size_f(D, r=1):
    z = 0
    for i in range(len(D)):
        for j in range(len(D)):
            if D[i] > D[j] * r:
                z += 1
    return z

ratios = []
ns = np.arange(3, 19)
nums = []
denoms = []
for n in ns:
    x = np.array(list(map(len, powerset(np.arange(n)))))
    nd = size_f(x, r=1.1)
    ratio = float(nd) / float((len(x) ** 2))
    nums.append(nd)
    denoms.append(len(x)**2)
    ratios.append(ratio)
plt.scatter(ns, ratios)
plt.ylabel('|ND|/|n||d|')
plt.xlabel('|n|')
```
````

Comment: Are $N$ and $D$ two copies of the same set?

Comment: If I understand correctly, $D = P( \{0,1, \ldots,k \})$ , or the power set of $[k]$, so since $\emptyset \in D$, wouldn’t $ND$ be empty?